# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

tengo un error que no entiendo porque se muestra, tengo dos clases una es la clase llamada Dialogo que extiende de un DialogFragment, en este clase tengo un metodo que se llama **onClickGuardarPersona**, esta clase la uso para crear un cuadro de dialogo pero al momento de dar clic en el boton que ejecuta el metodo **onClickGuardarPersona** me marca un error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.io.FileOutputStream
>   android.app.Activity.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null
>   object reference
>   atcom.example.enriq.myapplication.ServicioArchivo.guardar(ServicioArchivo.java:41)

De la clase Dialogo se ejecuta el metodo **onClickGuardarPersona** este metodo llama a la clase ServicioArchivo para ejecutar el metodo **Guardar**, ahi es donde marca el error.

Esta es la clase Dialogo completa, el metodo de onClickGuardarPersona se encuentra al final de la clase:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Enriq on 30/01/2018.
 */

public class Dialogo extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private ArrayList<Registro_parqueo> lista;
    private String archivo = "parquimetro.obj";
    View view;

    private RecyclerView notasRecyclerView;
    private EditText editNota;
    private NotaAdapter adapter;
    private ServicioArchivo servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity());


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        final EditText matricula = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
        final EditText clienesillo = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.cliente);

        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        onClickGuardarPersona(matricula.getText().toString(),clienesillo.getText().toString());

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Dialogo.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo) {
        try {
            servicio.agregarNota(matricula+"\n"+clienesillo);
            adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(servicio.leerNotas()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nota agregada con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al agregar la nota", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

La clase donde esta el metodo **guardar** es la siguiente:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Next University.
 */
public class ServicioArchivo {

    private Activity activity;
    private String notas="";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "notas.txt";

    public ServicioArchivo(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void agregarNota(String nota) throws IOException {
        notas = notas.concat("".equals(notas) ? "" : ";");
        notas = notas.concat(nota);
        guardar();
    }

    public String[] leerNotas() throws IOException {
        cargar();
        return notas.split(";");
    }

    public String leerNotas(int posicion) throws IOException {
        cargar();
        String[] listaNotas = notas.split(";");
        return listaNotas[posicion];
    }

    private void guardar() throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(notas.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }

    private void cargar() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = activity.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        int c;
        notas = "";
        while ( (c = fis.read()) != -1) notas += String.valueOf((char)c);
        fis.close();
    }

    public void eliminar(){
        activity.deleteFile(FILE_NAME);
        notas="";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de llamar el método `agregarNota()` debes asegurar que la instancia servicio en realidad reciba el contexto para que funcione  correctamente, por lo tanto solo declara la variable `ServicioArchivo`:

```
//private ServicioArchivo servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity());
private ServicioArchivo servicio;
```

pero inicializala dentro de este método:

```
public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo) {
    try {

        //* Inicializar
        servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity()); 

        servicio.agregarNota(matricula+"\n"+clienesillo);
        adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(servicio.leerNotas()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nota agregada con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al agregar la nota", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```